# decision tree and prediction

Tags: decision-trees

A decision tree regression model produces at most as many possible predictions as it has terminal nodes/leaves. A well fit decision tree will have been limited in the number of terminal nodes/leaves, to prevent overfitting. A histogram of predicted values will have at most the **same number of bins with non-zero values, while certain bins within the range of the target variable will have no predictions, creating a “step” like pattern that will not appear smooth.**

do you know what this line means?